# Finding $f(x)$ given $ f(\frac{x}{x+1})=x^2 $

Tags: calculus

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which is defined $f(\frac{x}{x+1})=x^2$. Find $f(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

Call

$$
y = \frac{x}{1 + x}
$$

then

$$
xy + y = x \quad\Rightarrow\quad x = \frac{y}{1 - y}
$$

And so

$$
f(y) = \frac{y^2}{(1-y)^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Now at least I have a wider understanding of what I actually need to do.